# How can I zoom on a marker from a specific search bar created on Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to zoom on my markers from a search bar that is created with Javascript. This search bar has an autocomplete form and this function works well. But, when I select one of my glacier ( I'm working with swiss glaciers) from the select bar, there is no interaction and I don't really understand how I could create this interaction.

I don't have lots of experience in Javascript, HTML... So if you can be as clear as possible, it could be cool! I am sure that all the information of the glaciers are stored on a sql database.

Here is a part of my code that could be important:

HTML part:

```
 <body>
    <div class = "main">
  <div id="map" class="glaciers"></div>
  <div id= "coordonnees">Coordonnées: déplacez la souris sur la carte</div>
  <div class = "sidebar_gl">
    <p class= "explication"> Choix du glacier:</p>
    <form autocomplete="off" id= "glacier_form" action="zoom_barre">
      <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
        <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myGlacier" placeholder="Glaciers">
      </div>
      <input id = "button_submit" type="submit">
    </form>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript part:

```
function show_glaciers(){

  var url = '/glaciers_info.json';

  $.getJSON(url, function(data){
    var dict={};
    for (var i=0; i <data.length; i++){
      var glacier = data[i];
      dict[glacier.nom]=ajouter_marqueur_glacier(glacier);
    }
        GlacierDictionary =dict; // store Globale
    autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), Object.keys(dict));
    });

}

show_glaciers();
function zoom_barre(glacier){
$('#myInput').on('change', function(e){
  var id_glacier = $('#myInput').val();
  if (id_glacier == "") return;
  var glacier = glacier[id_glacier]
  mymap.panTo(([glacier.y, glacier.x]), {animate: true});
   mymap.flyTo(([glacier.y, glacier.x]),14);
});
}
zoom_barre()
}
```

Thanks for your answer

Comment: The code references `mymap` but it doesn't appear to be defined. Is it perhaps a Google Map?

Comment: No No, I just didnt put all my javascript code in this part because he's really big. all my variables are defined so this isn't a problem. And no, it isn't a Google map, i've just created my own map with Leaflet.